# Remember search params

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new in mvc and I try to create a simple page with table and ajax search.

For example, I have a search model, which pass parameters from form to controller.

Model:

```
public class OrderSearchViewModel
{
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Lang), Name = "OrderID")]
    public int? OrderID { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Lang), Name = "DeliveryType")]
    public int? DeliveryTypeID { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Lang), Name = "Partner")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public SelectList DeliveryTypes { get; set; }

}
```

In controller I have an action witch return View with form:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var ordersSearchModel = // default init;
  return View(model);
}
```

In my Index.cshtml I have a form

```
@model Models.Order.OrderSearchViewModel

<div class="row">

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Orders", "Order", new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "ordersList"}, new {@id = "searchForm", @class = "form-horizontal"}))
{
         // Editors templates for each params           
}
</div>

<div id="ordersList" class="row">

</div>  
}
```

In my Controller I have a method, witch take search model and return a partial view

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Orders(OrderSearchViewModel model, int page = 1, int pageSize = 50)
{
  var models = // connect to db and get data filtered by model params   
  return PartilaView("_View", models);         
}
```

In result partial I have a table with order num and link to edit view.
In edit view I have a link back to search:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", "Order", new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

And by click this link I get the Index view in default (without search parameters) and user must fill it once again. 
What will be the best practice to remember user search parameters?
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you need the search filter for just the next request, you can use TempData.

Comment: Such use cases it would be a better practice to use query parameters

Answer (score 0):

As devqon said, the preferred approach is to use query parameters, but it does sound like your usage might make this a bit difficult to manage

TempData/SessionData may solve your issue, but using this approach will cause problems if the user decides to use your application in multiple tabs/windows (they will all share the same search params)

Something that might be worth looking into is SessionStorage.(Link below)

This type of storage persists as long as the browser stays open

And importantly

> Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated

So your pages shouldn't share state.

More details here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage